# SQL Maximum number of doctors in a department

Tags: sql, t-sql

my problem is this:
I have a table named

```
Doctor(id, name, department)
```

and another table named

```
department(id, name).
```

a Doctor is associated with a department (only one department, not more)

I have to do a query returning the department with the maximum number of doctors associated with it.

I am not sure how to proceed, I feel like I need to use a nested query but I just started and I'm really bad at this.
I think it should be something like this, but again I'm not really sure and I can't figure out what to put in the nested query:

```
SELECT department.id  
FROM (SELECT FROM WHERE) , department d, doctor doc  
WHERE doc.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach to the "Find ABC with the maximum number of XYZs" problem in SQL is as follows:

- Query for a list of ABCs that includes each ABC's count of XYZs
- Order the list in descending order according to the count of XYZs
- Limit the result to a single item; that would be the top item that you need.

In your case, you can do it like this (I am assuming MySQL syntax for taking the top row):

```
SELECT *
FROM department dp
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM doctor d WHERE d.department_id=dp.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Group BY`

```
Select top (1) department.id,count(Doctor.*) as numberofDocs
from department inner join Doctor on  Doctor.id = department.id
Group by department.id
Order by count(Doctor.*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally avoid using sub queries in MySQL due to a well known [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47914) in MySQL. Due to the bug, MySQL executes the inner query for every single outer query result. Therefore, if you have 10 departments, then doctor query would be executed 10 times. The bug may have been fixed in MySQL 5.6. In this particular case the number of departments may not be large, therefore performance may not be your main concern. However, the following solution should work for MySQL and much more optimized. The answer by [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) is almost the same, just got ahead of me :). But MySQL does not support the command top.

```
select dep.id, dep.name, count(doc.id) as dep_group_count from Doctor doc join department dep on doc.department = dep.id group by doc.department order by dep_group_count DESC LIMIT 1
```